# Extracting Columns from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assuming I have a numpy array

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
```

and I want to access it row wise I can do

```
for row in A:
  print(row)
```

which results in me having

```
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
```

Is there a similar column wise method to access the array 
which will result in me having

```
[1 5]
[2 6]
[3 7]
[4 8]
```

I know I can use indices but, I just want to know if there is a way to access the array column wise without indices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transposing the array should get you what you want:

```
for item in A.T:
    print(item)
```

The `T` proprety is short for the `transpose()` method and returns a view on the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could select the `i`th column of A, like so:

```
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    print(A[:, i])
```

Comment: sorry I do not want to use indices